# Using the <audio>Tag with adobe air

Tags: html, audio, air

Is there a way to use the html5 audio tag within an adobe air application-
without using javascript that is?  It is not ridiculously hard to play audio files with javascript but I was just wondering if its possible to simply use the audio tag in some way within the app. Of course the audio tag works in all my browsers but it's simply a no show within air.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably that the version of webkit AIR includes doesn't support that feature or there is a security sandbox violation perhaps. Not sure why you need to use the audio tag when you can simply load and play a sound. If it needs to be per-page you can even use the HTML location change event handler attached to the HTMLLoader object, check the location of the browser in this event (which is called when the user has navigated elsewhere) and then play sounds or do whatever this way. But anyway I'm sure its just the version of webkit they are using. They also strip it down and remove various features to make people happy, IE apple so they can submit apps using webkit with only features that apple would approve of.

Reference:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#LOCATION_CHANGE